# Save all results from pattern.finditer() object

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to capture and return a list of all matches of a regular expression pattern.  Consider the following example:

```
text_dict = {'text1':'1234abc456', 'text2':'123abe456xyz', 'text3':'123abd456'}

text_find = re.compile('\D+')
results = {}
for key, val in text_dict.items():
    for match in text_find.finditer(val):
        results[key] = match.group(0)
```

The printed `results` dictionary returns the following:

```
for k, v in results.items():
    print(k,v)

text1 abc
text2 xyz
text3 abd
```

However, this is not correct.  The results should be consistent with the printed return below:

```
for key, val in text_dict.items():
    for match in text_find.finditer(val):
        print(f'{key} {match.group(0)}')

text1 abc
text2 abe
text2 xyz
text3 abd
```

The match object only saves the last matched object when I assign the result to a dictionary.  If I use a list and append, the loop aggregates all the matches iteratively which is also incorrect.  How do I save all the matches to a list?

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. Use a list of tuples. See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AE4FAI)

Comment: for text2 when you loop the first time you tell the dict to store abe for text2, then you loop again and tell the dict now instaed store xyz for text2. you need to store the results in a list that you can append to with each new result.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary cannot hold multiple keys with the same id so the first results of text2 are overwritten by the second ones. You could use `defaultdict` to solve it:

```
from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                                                                                 

text_dict = {'text1':'1234abc456', 'text2':'123abe456xyz', 'text3':'123abd456'} 

text_find = re.compile('\D+') 
results = defaultdict(list) 
for key, val in text_dict.items(): 
   for match in text_find.finditer(val): 
      results[key].append(match.group(0))

print(results)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'text1': ['abc'], 'text2': ['abe', 'xyz'], 'text3': ['abd']})
```

Comment: I always forget about defaultdict and always preceed my append line with things like `if key not in results: results[key] = []` which work but deafultdict makes it simpler. I must must must remember them